# Eclipse - point cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, eclipse

What's the Problem?

Refer attached images for description.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please write your questions only in english also if here are several users which would also understand your german question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the top of the document, check if you can see an import like
`import android.R;`

If you do, delete it and add the right import for your project.

Comment: I have delete import android.R; and its work now.

Comment: No problem, it happens all the time when you accidentally select the wrong import from the eclipse popup.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have imported the R file `import android.R;`, 
Here is the more info on this error [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?rq=1)